# How to avoid browser variables in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, reactjs-flux

Recently I discovered Flux architecture and found [this, React starter kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit). Good structure, but, the application need to be compiled for browsers, from node.js with gulp.

I'm using [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest) for making ajax calls to server, reqwest need window , which on node.js isn't available. When I compile (using [gulp-render](https://github.com/koistya/gulp-render)) from ES 6 to ES 5.1, react render evaluate all *require(..)* files and give me error because window is not defined, how could I avoid this? Have you had to deal with something like this?

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at E:\projects\micaimportanta\node_modules\reqwest\reqwest.js:13:13
    at win (E:\projects\micaimportanta\node_modules\reqwest\reqwest.js:8:72)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projects\micaimportanta\node_modules\reqwest\reqwest.js:11:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at reactTransform (E:\projects\micaimportanta\gulpfile.js:65:5)
    at Object.Plugin.reactTransform (E:\projects\micaimportanta\node_modules\gulp-render\index.js:72:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to take a look at [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/blob/97d416cb3bc2ef531fae05a8eed4c86700ba4dc8/README.md)